# RecyclerView with Pictures and Strings as Data Types

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am making an app with a RecyclerView that needs to display 2 image views, and 3 text views. I follows the tutorials on the developers.android.com website, and it worked. Then I tried to edit the adaptor and now my activity doesn't work.

Here is my adaptor .java file:

```
package com.winansbros.soccerpredictor;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] mDataset1;
private String[] mDataset2;
private String[] mDataset3;
private Drawable[] mDataset4;
private Drawable[] mDataset5;

// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case

    public TextView team1textview;
    public TextView team2textview;
    public TextView scoretextview;
    public ImageView team1imageview;
    public ImageView team2imageview;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        team1textview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team1name);
        team2textview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.team2name);
        scoretextview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.card1score);
        team1imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.team1imageview);
        team2imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.team2imageview);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset, String[] myDataset2, String[] myDataset3, Drawable[] myDataset4, Drawable[] myDataset5) {
    mDataset1 = myDataset;
    mDataset2 = myDataset2;
    mDataset3 = myDataset3;
    mDataset4 = myDataset4;
    mDataset5 = myDataset5;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardviewwidget, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(10, 20, 10, 20);
    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.team1textview.setText(mDataset1[position]);
    holder.team2textview.setText(mDataset2[position]);
    holder.scoretextview.setText(mDataset3[position]);
    holder.team1imageview.setImageDrawable(mDataset4[position]);
    holder.team2imageview.setImageDrawable(mDataset5[position]);
}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset1.length;
}
}
```

Here is my History activity .java file

```
package com.winansbros.soccerpredictor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class History extends Activity {

Context CTX = this;

AdView mAdView;
AdRequest adRequest;

Button clearButton;
Button tipsButton;

StringBuilder sb;
DatabaseOperations DOP;

Integer team1image;
Integer team2image;

TypedArray imgs;

List<String> winners;
List<String> hometeams;
List<String> awayteams;
List<String> scores;
List<Drawable> homeimages;
List<Drawable> awayimages;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

Resources res;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    res = getResources();

    DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
    CR.moveToFirst();

    winners = new ArrayList<>();
    hometeams = new ArrayList<>();
    awayteams = new ArrayList<>();
    scores = new ArrayList<>();
    homeimages = new ArrayList<>();
    awayimages = new ArrayList<>();

    if( CR.moveToFirst() ) {
        getHistory();
    }

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(CTX);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    String[] myDataset = hometeams.toArray(new String[hometeams.size()]);
    String[] myDataset2 = awayteams.toArray(new String[awayteams.size()]);
    String[] myDataset3 = scores.toArray(new String[scores.size()]);
    Drawable[] myDataset4 = homeimages.toArray(new Drawable[homeimages.size()]);
    Drawable[] myDataset5 = awayimages.toArray(new Drawable[awayimages.size()]);


    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset, myDataset2, myDataset3, myDataset4, myDataset5);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearSQLite);
    tipsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TipsButton);

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("8AC41E108CD62B7703FF28358AEEC8BC")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    Log.d("Progress", "Far");

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            DatabaseOperations DOB = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
            DOB.DeleteInformation(CTX);
            DOB.close();
            finish();
        }
    });

    Log.d("Progress", "First On Click Listener");

    //sb = new StringBuilder();

    //historyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.historyText);
    //historyTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());



    tipsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TipsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Log.d("Progress", "second On Click Listener");

    DOP.close();
}

public void getHistory() {
    Log.i("GetHistory", "Initialized");

    Cursor CR = DOP.getInformation(DOP);
    CR.moveToFirst();


    do {
        winners.add(CR.getString(0));
        hometeams.add(CR.getString(1));
        awayteams.add(CR.getString(2));
        scores.add(CR.getString(3));
        Log.d("Cloud Files", "OBJECT ID SET");

    } while (CR.moveToNext());

    Log.d("GetHistory", "Lists all set");

    int size = winners.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (hometeams.get(i) == "Arsenal")
        {
            int resID = res.getIdentifier("arsenal", "drawable", getPackageName());
            homeimages.add(res.getDrawable(resID));
        }
        ...

        if (awayteams.get(i) == "Arsenal")
        {
            int resID = res.getIdentifier("arsenal", "drawable", getPackageName());
            awayimages.add(res.getDrawable(resID));
        }

        if (awayteams.get(i) == "West Ham")
        {
            int resID = res.getIdentifier("westham", "drawable", getPackageName());
            awayimages.add(res.getDrawable(resID));
        }
    }

    Log.d("GetHistory", "Images set");

    Log.d("Cloud Files", Integer.toString(size));

    Log.d("Cloud Files", awayimages.get(0).toString());

}
}
```

here is the cardview that is being used in the adaptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
tools:context="com.winansbros.soccerpredictor.History"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_gravity="center"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/team1imageview"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/team1name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/team2name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/team1imageview"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/team1imageview"
        android:width="100dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/card1score"
        android:width="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/team1name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/team1name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/team1name"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/team2name"
        android:width="100dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/team2imageview"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/team2imageview"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/team2imageview"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the History Activity XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear History"
        android:id="@+id/clearSQLite"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:width="150dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tips"
        android:id="@+id/TipsButton"
        android:width="150dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/clearSQLite"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, the logcat:

```
...
06-13 16:51:47.510    2085-2085/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor I/GetHistory﹕ Initialized
06-13 16:51:47.510    2085-2085/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor D/Cloud Files﹕ OBJECT ID SET
06-13 16:51:47.511    2085-2085/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor D/Cloud Files﹕ OBJECT ID SET
06-13 16:51:47.511    2085-2085/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor D/GetHistory﹕ Lists all set
06-13 16:51:47.511    2085-2085/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor D/GetHistory﹕ Images set
06-13 16:51:47.511    2085-2085/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor D/Cloud Files﹕ 2
06-13 16:51:47.511    2085-2085/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-13 16:52:07.545    2085-2095/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor I/art﹕ Thread[5,tid=2095,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4a33c00,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-13 16:52:07.545    2085-2095/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor I/art﹕ [ 06-13 16:52:07.745   546:  569 I/Process  ]
Sending signal. PID: 546 SIG: 3
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What happens? The logcat seems cut off right where the interesting stuff begins, ie,  a crash

Comment: @JHH the only extra output from the logcat are                                  06-13 16:52:07.545    2085-2095/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor I/art﹕ Thread[5,tid=2095,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4a33c00,peer=0x12c000a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3                                          
06-13 16:52:07.545    2085-2095/com.winansbros.soccerpredictor I/art﹕ [ 06-13 16:52:07.745   546:  569 I/Process  ]
    Sending signal. PID: 546 SIG: 3

Comment: Well, what *happens*?

Comment: @JHH when I press the button to go to the activity, my tablet's screen goes black, and the new activity never loads. Then the "App is not responding, do you want to close it?" prompt shows up.

Comment: See, that's useful info. An ANR means you are blocking the main thread. You posted a wall of code so it's not evident to me immediately where you are making the blocking call, but it's clear that you are making some database calls etc from your onCreate method, ie, from the main thread. You should offload any I/O to a separate thread. That said,  I can't see right now what exactly causes your ANR,  unless those db calls are simply very very slow. Start your debugger and pause the main thread, and see where it's hanging.